# Is it safe to install programs from an external removable drive?

Tags: installation

Case Scenario:
I have a USB Flash drive with an installer for a program, and I am currently using a NVMe SSD in my computer. I want to install a program from said Flash Drive to my computer.

Instead of copying the installer to my computer's NVMe SSD and then running it, I am running it from the removable media.

Are there any repercussions doing this? Is there an increased likelihood of failure installation if the installer is run from an external media such as USB Flash drives, external hard disks, etc?

Of course, the other alternative is copying the installer to the NVMe SSD and then running it. NVMe SSDs however have a finite number of writes before they fail however. If one were to install a lot of programs from an external drive back up and do it this way and if some of the installers of the programs are large in size, then it would contribute to the wear of the NVMe SSD.

Comment: Why wouldn’t it work?

Comment: I'm just used to copying installers to the desktop first from external drives before installing them. Just my habit since the days of HDDs. But now that I am using a NVMe SSD and aware of its finite write limitation, I guess its time to break the habit.

Some program installers may be sensitive to where they are running (i.e. if the program installer is scripted to source dependency files from within the local system or interacts within the directory it is running from while installation is in progress).

Comment: Windows users for years launched installers from external drives.  The installer will write anything it needs temporary on the system drive and Windows eventually will get rid of it

Comment: If you're concerned about finite writes on SSDs, you're misreading the data. Yes, there is a finite number of times a given cell can be written on an SSD, but that number is huge, and the average drive can handle many years of writes without experiencing failure. In other words: Your stated point of concern is not something you ought to be concerned about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is perfectly safe to run installers from external or temporary storage media. That has been perfectly safe for a long time, and continues to be perfectly safe.

The reason you are considering doing this is specious though: There's no compelling reason to actively avoid making writes on your SSD. Modern SSDs have far more write cycles built-in to their normal lifespan than you're likely ever to use unless you're doing constant writes and re-writes.